# modify udid,major id and minor id of beacon in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon, core-bluetooth, beacon

I want to develop an app like BeaconSet and LightBlue which modifies the values of the any kind of beacons. Till now,I have used CBCentralManager and CBPeripheral in app to retrieve all the value of the beacon which i can get through CBCharacteristics of CoreBluetooth framework from beacon. But when I tried to change the values of beacon like UDID, majorID and minorID of beacon through this below method

```
- (void)writeValue:(NSData *)data forCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic type:(CBCharacteristicWriteType)type;
```

then the values don't get change and also this peripheral delegate method is not called which is shown below.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(nullable NSError *)error;
```

So, how should I change this values?

Thanks

Comment: There is no standard method for setting these attributes of a beacon; each beacon manufacturer will have their own approach.  Often with some form of security to prevent attackers from maliciously changing the settings; e.g.. a code may need to be written to another attribute or changes can only be made immediately after the beacon is restarted.  You will need to refer to the beacon's manufacturer for their method

Comment: @Paulw11 I have two different beacon here and i have tried to change the values of both beacon one with LightBlue app and another with BeaconSet app. And I saw that they are rebooting the beacon by asking password. So How they are rebooting the beacon and applying the changes?